# Include html file in _layout.cshtml in runing Asp.Net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have html page in my ASP.NET MVC web project. I mean html not cshtml.
But I want to include _layout.cshtml in my html file as header offcourse.

If my file was test.cshtml
then on the top of the page I would write

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

But how to do if my file is just html , like test.html , not .cshtml? How can I include or implement
_Layout.cshtml in my test.html?

Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Countries</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
....
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't.  HTML pages do not undergo any server-side processing, they are just sent to the client.  You could make the page cshtml and create a route to go to the controller action when someone requests the .html page.

Comment: HTML basically doesn't have concept of layout pages, it is Razor engine who have that (just combining generated HTML tags between layout page and view page). You may want to create `Html.Action` which returning HTML file as intended.

Comment: @Paul Abbott , Aha.. Ok guys...now I know.. thank you for your response!

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto Aha.. Ok guys...now I know.. thank you for your response!

Comment: It is surely possible using url rewrite and redirect. But it is a bit complicated to implement.